# PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly

Tags: php, windows, installation, pear

I cnan't install pear 
it give error PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly. pearcmd.php could not be found there. Please fix it using environment variable or modify the default value is pear.bat the current value is: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0

**Note: Earlier I had installed php pear with selenium and later uninstalled it.**

Thanks in Advance Swapnil

Answer (score 0):

i faced a similar problem of ' PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR is not set correctly. '. the fix which worked for me was - 
1) checked the env var PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR
2) the path was not correct, in my case it had an extra backslash. removed it.
this fixed the problem. 
hope it helps.

Comment: Extra backlash where? at the beginning/middle/last where!! ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with that and solved it with

`putenv('PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=/path/to/my/pear');`

on top of the include file I included in every script.